# Sync between two Android devices without Internet connection

Tags: sync

Is it possible to sync between two Android devices directly when there is no Internet connection (like a remote location or an outage at the Internet provider)?

Using a direct wireless connection between just these two Android devices (without using a PC or a WiFi router)

I need to sync all data (contacts, calendar, photos, ...)

I asked the same question for iOS devices:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35515/sync-between-an-iphone-and-ipad-without-internet-connection

Comment: If wireless connection is not a hard requirement, you could probably use the microSD Card to transfer the content the old-fashioned way.  This is assuming of course that both devices you need to sync have removable storage.  You may also need 3rd-party apps for exporting and importing data from apps that don't provide export functionality on their own.

Comment: Wireless sync is a hard requirement. Needing to transfer using a memory card or cable adds too much complexity to the point I will not be doing sync so frequently. You are also suggesting multiple programs to add even more complexity.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid this isn't possible, at least with the builtin apps. All of the sync profiles are client-side, and can't act as sync servers. Furthermore, normal Android phones don't support ad-hoc wifi connection, so you'd need to connect through a router or possibly with bluetooth.

Some of these can be achieved manually over bluetooth, such as sending photos and contacts, but you'd have to manually select which files to send. For photos, go to `Gallery`, select the photos you want to send, and tap the `Share` icon and select `Bluetooth`. After this you need to select the other device, assuming it's paired. A similar menu should be found in your `Contacts` app.

Answer (score -1):

There is an `Android` app called [Bump](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bumptech.bumpga&hl=en) in the market, that can do what you asked for. You need to make sure that the receiver has the app on his phone as well, and then you're good to go!. It's an app based on `NFC` and it can used for transferring contacts, photos and even web pages. Hope this helps.

Comment: Bump does not meet my requirement as it requires a solid connection to the Internet: http://bu.mp/faq#general

Comment: It's hard to sync without an active internet connection. Probably the removal of sd card and then transferring would be the best option.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at  http://www.fjsoft.at/en/ I gave found it works well, and its easy

Comment: Could you please add some more details to what you linked to, and how it heps the questioner? Especially how a Windows application shall help to, I quote from the question, *sync between two Android devices directly*?